# Does jQuery have a on/live hover function for mouseenter or mouseout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basically having a little trouble with a <li> of items, that I am running a plugin through, which dynamically adds a data-tag ID to the data-* attribute.

This for some reason means that all items are dynamically added, and another function I am running on the same list elements won't run, because the event isn't dynamically attached.

What happens is:
1) Page renders
2) My 'other' function is available whilst DOM is loading
3) Page loads, the plugin code is available, but my 'other' function (which adds a hover box title which comes from below and animates up) no longer works. So it basically works until the other plugin kicks in.

My findings so far are:

I can use the jQuery 'on' to dynamically attach events to dynamically edited/created items (the #stage li items). Using this:

```
$('body').on('hover', '#stage li', function() {
    // Do dynamic stuff
}
```

But this only works with 1 hover, and doesn't give me a mouseenter/mouseout solution which I really need. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, it's called [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Comment: Hover removed in version 1.9 in the form you refer: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup:

```
$('#stage').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // do mouseentery shtuff
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // mouse bye bye
    }
},'li');
```

Changed .on() event binding from `body` to `#stage` and filter `li` from there, because it will be faster.

The cool thing about doing it this way (the XML way) is that you can easily add more stuff to it ... adding a mousemove function is just another comma and function below it in the same item, all contained within the one .on() binding. :)

Comment: +1 yes always better to bind at the closest point to limit the traversal for the event - I was actually looking at that as you changed it.

Comment: haha i keep telling people on here that. ud be shocked at the number of people that bind to `$(document)`!

Comment: FYI, for those wanting to research based on these comments, this binding stuff is the "context" of the bind - similar to when context was added to selectors in version 1.3 but even more important for "on()" with dynamic elements as related to the DOM and how far the traversal needs to go.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - What does the 'context' of the bind exactly mean Mark?

Comment: @Toddo - http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery should give you a start

Comment: And here, he talks about delegation (think .on()) http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for. Also, note that hover is no longer supported as of jQuery 1.9

```
$('mydiv').on('mouseenter', '#stage li', function( event ) {
    // do something
}).on('mouseleave', '#stage li', function( event ) {
    // do something different
});
```

Comment: You should put the #stage in where you have mydiv and leave the li where it is in this form.

Comment: Great answer, I went for the one above as it's 'faster', and a little shorter! Thank you very much for answering though.